# Parent div not following size change when child:hover

Tags: html, css

Okey so the problem is that the `#page` wont follow the size change, i want the `#page` to be 100% height when i hover `#text3`

http://jsfiddle.net/2EfLz/38/

Comment: `id`s must be unique in the DOM (*`#txt` is not*). self closing tags have the `/` at the end like this `<br/>` and not `</br>`

Comment: @Anton Consider accepting an answer if one has solved your problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `height:100%` to `min-height:100%` on `#page`. That way it's not restricted and can grow when needed, but will not be less than 100%.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2EfLz/49/

Answer (score 1):

add this to your javascript:

```js
$('text3').addEvents({
  mouseover: function(){ 
    var windowHeight = window.getSize().y;
    var text3Height = $('text3').getPosition().y;
    var t3fHeight = $('t3f').getSize().y;

    // padding-top + padding-bottom + border-top + border-bottom
    var paddingHeight = 42; 

    $('text3').setStyles({
      'height':windowHeight - text3Height - t3fHeight - paddingHeight + 'px',
      'overflow':'auto'
    })
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $('text3').setStyles({
      'height':'75px', // initial value
      'overflow':'hidden'
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified a fixed height it cannot extend..

Use `min-height` instead

```
min-height: 100%;
```